# R round product between positive real numbers x and y to between 0 and 1 efficiently

Tags: r, if-statement, rounding

I am having this function to make products between two positive number that returns the product if this it less or equal to 1, otherwise returns 1.

```
f1 <- function(x, y) ifelse(x*y <= 1, x*y, 1)
```

It annoys me that I have to do the x*y calculation twice - is there a base R function that can do this, or another way to do the task ? I am aware that the difference in computing time perhaps is small (is it O vs 2*O ?) but still ... and out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create the object and then do the assignment

```
out <- x*y
out[out >1] <- 1
```

---

Or another option is `pmin`

```
out1 <- pmin(x*y, 1)
```

-checking

```
identical(out, out1)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- abs(rnorm(10, 0.5))
y <- abs(rnorm(10, 0.7))
```

Comment: Yes - that first one never crossed my mind because all my `x`s and `y`s are length 1 - I need to do this repeatedly (trillion of times). The second option suits me better.